# Looking for an alternative to the Windows defrag utility

Tags: windows-xp, defragment

Under Windows XP, what are some alternatives to the default disk defragmenter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Defraggler](http://www.defraggler.com/) from the same guys who brought you CCleaner and Recuva! All are great pieces of software.

Comment: I found Defraggler far too slow for full drive defrag. My drive is only 500Gb and only 48% full; after 10 minutes of defragging, it was only 2% done.

Answer (score 15):

[JKdefrag](http://www.kessels.com/Jkdefrag/) is what I have been using to great effect.  It's also Free!

Comment: run it as a screen-saver

Comment: Jeroen Kessels recently released the 4.0 version and changed the name to MyDefrag.

Comment: jkdefrag is a lot simpler than mydefrag - personally i've been sticking to jkdefrag since i don't want the fancy options - i just want it to do what i need it to do, without bothering me with the minitae.

Answer (score 3):

I was using [O&O Defrag](http://www.oo-software.com/) for years, but recently switched to [PerfectDisk](http://www.perfectdisk.com/). PerfectDisk is still able to defragment even when the hard drive has very little free disk space.

Comment: PerfectDisk is great, best defrag tool I've ever used by far. However, it's a lot more than most people need, so I'd be more inclined to recommend something free such as Defraggler.

Comment: @SashaChedygov [PerfectDisk now has a free version](http://blog.raxco.com/2012/03/29/perfectdisk-free-defrag-beta/).

Answer (score 2):

[PerfectDisk](http://www.perfectdisk.com/) is one that actually works and is not totally annoying. :)

Comment: Would like to add here that [PerfectDisk now has a free version](http://blog.raxco.com/2012/03/29/perfectdisk-free-defrag-beta/).

Answer (score 1):

[Power Defragmenter](http://www.excessive-software.eu.tt/), a free GUI for Sysinternals' [Contig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contig_(defragmentation_utility)).  Haven't used the latest version, but I found that the previous version's Power Defragment mode was both fast and effective.

Answer (score 1):

DisKeeper is good.. has a managed version for enterprise. http://www.diskeeper.com/

Answer (score 0):

O&O Defrag, http://www.oo-software.com/home/en/products/oodefrag/index.html.

It will actually move files around (instead of just 
defragging individual files). In this way files that are in 
the same folder will all be physically be close on the disk.

It can also defrag files that are in use by Windows (e.g. 
the MFT) by doing defragging at boot time. This however requires 
that the defragging runs as a result of being defined in a 
job.

I can recommend it. I have used it for many years without 
any problems and it is not intrusive; there is no noticeable 
degradation in performance while it runs.